# Possible to reverse a permanent redirect in Azure?

Tags: redirect, azure

I have an azure web site that I don't update anymore.

So I edited the `web.config` and added a rule to redirect to a new URL.

I made a type when typing the new URL and set the redirect mode to permanent.

No matter what I do, now I can not correct it because it seems it's permanently stuck this way.

The old URL now tries to redirect to some random incorrect typo location.

Is there a way to reverse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it may be a local issue. Your browser may have cached the 302 response. Have you tried using a different browser, or clearing your browser's cache?

Otherwise, have you restarted the web site through the Azure portal?